# Microsoft Azure Xamarin App - Switch from Login screen to Forgot Password screen

Tags: c#, ios, azure

I am having trouble with the following code. The login view displays as a modal view, and when the user clicks forgot password, it catches the error and tries to put up another modal view. Problem is that the first modal has not cleared yet. I don't see a way to tell it to call the second view only after the first one completes. Can someone help me with this?

```
try
      {
        var platformParameters = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        AppDelegate.AuthenticationClient.PlatformParameters = new PlatformParameters(platformParameters);
        var authenticationResult = await AppDelegate.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(AppDelegate.Scopes, "", UiOptions.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, AppDelegate.Authority, AppDelegate.SignUpSignInPolicy);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        if (ex.Message != null && ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
        {
          await OnForgotPassword();
        }
        else { 
          Console.WriteLine("Exception message: " + ex.Message);
        }

      }
 }

 private async Task OnForgotPassword()
    {
      try
      {
       var result = await AppDelegate.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
          AppDelegate.Scopes,
          string.Empty,
          UiOptions.SelectAccount,
          string.Empty,
          null,
          AppDelegate.Authority,
          AppDelegate.PasswordResetPolicy);
      }
      catch (MsalException)
      {

      }

    }
```